# Callback after JSON

Tags: javascript

I have 3 functions: `initializeData`, `initializecartGroup` and `initializeCartGroupItem`. `initializeData` runs through a given forms groups and JSON parses those into data objects. The other two "helper" functions run through the individual groups and items also parsing. I need to set up a callback in the data function for the helper functions but I have no idea how. Can anyone help me out here? The ultimate goal is to find all of the div's on a given form containing the information, convert it to data objects, and then output it back to the page in a given DOM element.

```
function initializeData() {
    var cartGroups = document.querySelector('.cartGroups');
    if (null !== cartGroups) {
        var data = JSON.parse(cartGroups.innerHTML);
        data.forEach(function (cartGroup, index) {
            var group = new cartGroup();
            data.forEach(function (cartGroupItem, index) {
                var item = new cartGroupItem();
            });
        });
    }
}

function initializeCartGroup() {
    var cartGroup = document.querySelector('.cartGroup');
    if (null !== cartGroup) {
        var data = JSON.parse(cartGroup.innerHTML);
    }
}

function initializeCartGroupItem() {
    var cartGroupItem = document.querySelector('.cartGroupItem');
    if (null !== cartGroupItem) {
        var data = JSON.parse(cartGroupItem.innerHTML);
    }
}
```

Comment: The `innerHTML` of a DOM element contains a string value which you are going to parse as JSON? Can you show us the HTML/DOM you are running this against? Your `initializeCartGroup` and `initializeGroupItem` functions set a data variable, but then do nothing with it, and pass it nowhere? Where are `initializeCartGroup` and `initializeCartGroupItem` called from? Where is `cartGroupItem` defined?

Comment: I knew I would run into this problem and I should have elaborated. This file  is dependent on two seperate modules, group and item respecitvely. The data that is declared in group and item will eventually be used.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's an example of using a call back -

```
function initializeData(callback) {
    var cartGroups = document.querySelector('.cartGroups');
    if (null !== cartGroups) {
        var data = JSON.parse(cartGroups.innerHTML);
        data.forEach(function (cartGroup, index) {
            var group = new cartGroup();
            data.forEach(function (cartGroupItem, index) {
                var item = new cartGroupItem();
            });
        });
        callback();
    }

}
```

When calling the init function -

```
initializeData(initializeCartGroup);
```

This will run the callback function initializeCartGroup after the forEach loop.

Comment: You never execute the callback. `callback;` should be `callback();`